# Get auth from topdesk site being opened within iframe

Tags: api

I have a topdesk board, and connected external site via url, so my site is opened within iframe from topdesk.

My task is to get logged in user (at least its email) from topdesk.
I have found so far this api: https://developers.topdesk.com/explorer/?page=supporting-files#/Persons/getLoggedInPerson

But it requires to get auth key from login/password, but I do not user login/password from UI side.

So I do not see any straightforward solution, but maybe I could somehow to get cookie from parent topdesk view or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not possible, as it would be an enormous security vulnerability. If you would be able to go into an iFrame and interact with the embedded document, or go from an embedded page to its parent and interact with its document (e.g. retrieve the session cookies, read the contents of the page, etc.) it would become really easy to take over someones session and do malicious things.

For instance, as a malicious actor, I could place a small iFrame on my site in which I load TOPdesk. If you were already logged in into TOPdesk, you would also be logged in in the iFrame on my site. If I would be able to interact with the cookies within that iFrame, I could retrieve your session cookies and impersonate you.

Therefore, you can only interact on this level with iFrames that are on the same origin, also known as the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access).

However, even if you would be on the same origin, you would still not be able to read TOPdesk's session cookies, because they are set to [HttpOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies). This means the cookies can only be used by the browser itself, and can't be interacted with from JavaScript.

So, to me, it sounds like the only option you have is to interact with the API in the official way, through an application password. However, that might not be possible with what you are trying to achieve. Can you tell a little bit more about your use case?

Comment: Thank you, my case is I have my own web page integrated within topdesk, but my page requires authentication, and everything is fine until the moment, that user should login two times, first time log in to topdesk and second time to my application, but we use the same sso mechanism. So I thought may be I could use that information.

Comment: No, you can't use the login information from TOPdesk for that. However, if they use the same SSO, you might be able to change the configuration of your SSO provider, your app or TOPdesk, so it won't ask you for credentials again if you already have a session.